# Convert 5 minutes values to 15 minutes values

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following data as Dataframe:

[image: Dataframe]

As can be seen, the data is available in 5 minute steps. Now i want to convert the 5-min steps to 15-min steps. The columns "Verbrauch (kWh)" and "Leistung" should convert to the mean of the 15-min intervall.

I am able to convert to hourly data with the following:

```
df.groupby(df["Zeitpunkt"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-')).mean()
```

But how do i do that with 15min steps?

Comment: Average 3 successive values. But I would do a comparison to the 15 minute values based on 00, 15, 30, 45 etc just to see how they correlate.

Comment: This won't work because there are jumps in the data

Comment: Then you don't have the 5 minute steps you said you had. So now you have to adjust the calculations as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first replace **"_"** with nan:

```
import numpy as np
df = df.replace('_', np.nan)
```

then use **resample** and get means:

```
df['Zeitpunkt']=pd.to_datetime(df['Zeitpunkt'])
final= df.set_index('Zeitpunkt').sort_index().resample('15Min').agg({'Verbrauch (kWh)':'mean','Leistung':'mean'})
```